# How do I add an aggregate column in Kotlin DataFrame that is based on current row against other filtered rows?

Tags: dataframe, kotlin

```
val country by columnOf("UK", "UK", "FR", "FR", "DE")
val city by columnOf("London", "London", "Paris", "Paris", "Bonn")
val area by columnOf("Holborn", "Camden", "Barbes", "Eiffel", "Weststadt"), 
val population by columnOf(1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500) 

val df = dataFrameof (country, city, area, population) 
println(df)
```

How can I add a column which is population / sum by (country, city). This column would be calculated as follows:

```
Proportion
0.47826087  (i.e. 1100/2300)
0.52173913
0.481481481
0.518518519
1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to work but not sure if there is a better way

```
val country by columnOf("UK", "UK", "FR", "FR", "DE")
val city by columnOf("London", "London", "Paris", "Paris", "Bonn")
val area by columnOf("Holborn", "Camden", "Barbes", "Eiffel", "Weststadt"), 
val population by columnOf(1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500) 

val df = dataFrameof (country, city, area, population) 

val total by column<Int>()
val cities = df
    .groupBy { country and city }
    .aggregate{ sum { population } into total }

val df2 = df.add("percentage") {
    val filtercity = get(city)
    val cityTotal = cities.filter { city<String>() == filtercity}[total].first()
    get(population).div(cityTotal.toDouble())
}
println(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can add a new column, where you will immediately save the sum for each city. Then just update it:

```
df
    .add("percentage") { df.filter { c -> c.city == it.city }.sum().population.toDouble() }
    .update("percentage") { population / "percentage"<Double>() }
```

or

```
df
    .join(df.groupBy { city }.sum("percentage") { population })
    .convert("percentage") { population.toDouble() / "percentage"<Int>() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```kotlin
df.groupBy { country }.updateGroups {
    val sum = sum { population }.toDouble()
    add("proportion") { population() / sum }
}.concat()
```

We:

- Group by country
- Update each group to calculate the sum of the population in it
- We add a new column `proportion` to each group where each row is built up by taking the `population` at that row, divided by the previously calculated sum.
- Finally, we concatenate the groups so it becomes a normal DataFrame again.

Take a look at the [Documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/dataframe/groupby.html) if you want to find out what else is possible with `Group By` :).